# Add onScroll Event to React NavBar

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, event-handling

I'm trying to add an `onScroll` event to my React navbar. What's supposed to happen is whenever the user scrolls and the collapsible navbar is open, it will make the navbar collapsed.

I'm not sure if I'm going about it the right way, as I'm getting compilation errors, which I'm not sure how to fix.

Relevant Code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Slide from 'react-reveal/Slide';
import onClickOutside from 'react-onclickoutside';

// CSS import statements
import '../css/NavBar.css'

function NavBar() {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    NavBar.handleClickOutside = () => setOpen(false);

    
    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    }
    
    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    }
    
    handleScroll(event) {
        setOpen(false);
    }

    return(
        <Slide top>
                <nav onScroll={handleScroll}>
                    <div className='navbar-container'>
                        <h4 className='logo'>Daniel Zhang</h4>
                        <div className='toggle-button' onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
                            <div className='bar' />
                            <div className='bar' />
                            <div className='bar' />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id='nav-links' className={open ? 'nav-open' : 'nav-collasped'}>
                        <a href='/'>Home</a>
                        <a href='/about'>About</a>
                        <a href='/blog'>Blog</a>
                        <a href='/contact'>Contact</a>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </Slide>
        );
}

const clickOutsideConfig = {
    handleClickOutside: () => NavBar.handleClickOutside,
};

export default onClickOutside(NavBar, clickOutsideConfig);
```

Comment: what compilation error says?

Comment: If you want to use functional components and use the lifecycles functions, you have to use the `useEffect` function. If you want to use the lifecycle functions like that, use the class option. Read here https://itnext.io/add-state-and-lifecycle-methods-to-function-components-with-react-hooks-8e2bdc44d43d

Comment: The error says: `Line 13:25:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"`